# ProFTPD stops working after a few transfers

Tags: ftp, proftpd

My ProFTPD server is able to accept connections for a while, but after about 5-6 transfers or 10 minutes it all further transfers fail.

It doesn't matter if they are uploads or downloads, but I have noticed when uploading it often creates an empty file, then asks me if I want to overwrite it.

The only way I have found to resolve this issue is to restart the server, simply reconnecting the client does not help.

I have checked `netstat` and `ps`, and everything looks as I would have expected it to

```
Server: ProFTPD Version 1.3.4a
Client: FileZilla 3.5.3 (Windows)
Connection: implicit TLS
```

Config which may be important:

```
ServerType                      standalone
AllowRetrieveRestart            on
AllowStoreRestart               on
MaxInstances                    30
```